# How can I create a boolean in the `if` statement within the for loop to check for existence of term prepended to filename %%f?

Tags: batch-file

I have lyrics for about 60% of my song collection.  The filename of the lyrics is the same as the file name of song with `zzz_` prepended to the filename and `.lrc` as the extension.

```
C:\Songs\album\song.mp3
C:\Songs\album\zzz_song.lrc
```

I currently print the file names like so

```
for /r "C:\Songs" %%f in (*.mp3 *.flac) do (    
    echo %%f
)
```

How can I create a boolean in the `if` statement within the for loop as a check on the existence of lyrics files?

I was thinking something like

```
if exist zzz_%f echo zzz_%f.lrc
```

but `zzz_%f` prepends `zzz_` to the full file path (ex. `zzz_C:\Songs\album\song.mp3`) and `.lrc` is appended to the existing extension

Comment: A bad formulated question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`for` allows several modifiers to be used with its variables, as per your example `%%~nf` will give you just base name (no path, no extension). To see more, run `help for` from command line, they are well explained there.

Comment: I already know what `%%~nf` does, what boolean should I use in my if statement?

Comment: @user784637 If you do, then what *exact* problem do you have? Combining modifiers and your literals in `exist` so they form proper fully qualified name is all you need to do. Edit your question with what you've tried already.

Answer (score -1):

Use `%%~nxf` modifier to get filename with extension and %%~pf to get current file path.

```
@echo off
@set prefix=zzz_
for /r "C:\Songs" %%f in (*.mp3 *.flac) do (
  IF EXIST "%%~pf%prefix%%%~nxf" echo "%%~pf%prefix%%%~nxf"
)
```

*Command variables:*

```
%%~nxf   file name and extension;
%%~nf    file name;
%%~xf    file extension;
%%~pf    file path;
```